# Closest match in a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, levenshtein-distance

I have a `select` element containing different titles; as an example:

```
<select name="titles">
  <option value="1">Mr.</option>
  <option value="2">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="3">Ms.</option>
  <option value="4">Dr.</option>
  [..]
</select>
```

Then I have a string that contains a user-submitted title (originally written in a freeform textbox). My task is to make selected the `option` in the `select` that corresponds to that title.

However, it occurs to me that users are sometimes stupid.

The user-supplied string I search with could be "dr." or "Dr" or something like that. I need to match it with the most relevant one (i.e. "Dr." instead of "Mr.", both of them close to say, "dr.").

How would I go about this? I've only ever done approximate matching with MySQL's `LIKE` and PHP's `levenshtein()`, neither of which to my understanding are rather relevant in JS.

jQuery 1.7.1 is available. IE6 compatibility doesn't concern me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want kind of auto complete functionality ??

Comment: No, I get the string from a database source, and I need a way to change the selected option after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the only reasonable (and acceptable) variations are capital letter / no capital letter at the beginning and a missing point character at the end.

If that's the case then you can simply compare the user string to each of the items in the `select` with the above in mind:

- Convert first character of user input to uppercase.
- Add a `.` to the end of the string if the user string does not end with `.`.
- Compare the modified user string with each of the elements in `select` and see if one matches.

Comment: That would definitely work for the examples I listed (and I'm embarrassed that something so simple didn't occur to me), but trouble arrives with some of the weirder honorifics like "Lt. Cmdr.", "LCpl.", "MEP". These (and some others) will have many more alternative spellings.

Comment: For those sort of examples (Lt. Cmdr. etc) you might need to put each variation of each option on the `<option>`. Something like `<option value="7" data-variations="lt cmdr;lcpl">Lt Commander</option>`.

Answer (score 2):

The users are never stupid  ;)

Before you do the matching I would first make transform my all letters to lowecase in my javascript, then i would look for dots (.) and mabye remove them or add them to you match-string (its your choise).

Answer (score 1):

Hope that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Date: 2012-04-05 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var title = "dr"
        $("#titles option").each(function(i, el) {
            var re = new RegExp(title, 'ig')
            if ($(el).html().match(re)) {
                $(el).attr("selected", "selected");
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="titles" id="titles">
      <option value="1">Mr.</option>
      <option value="2">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="3">Ms.</option>
      <option value="4">Dr.</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And another solution to your issue - give your users exactly this form so they will have no  chance to type in any wrong data.

Comment: Otherwise good, but it also added `selected` to "Cmdr." and "Lt. Cmdr.", due to matching "Dr.". Any fix for that?

Comment: Yeah, replace regexp with this one: `var re = new RegExp("^" + title + ".*$", 'i')`

Comment: Thanks! Although, doesn't that one also run into trouble with titles that don't have a period in them? Like "MEP", "Sir", "DA", etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider stripping the extra layer of matching a freeform string to a list item? Maybe have an autocomplete field/dropdown or similar; seems excessive to have user enter and re-select the same data twice.

I was going to suggest looking into a fuzzy search algorithm, but wouldn't it be simpler to have an array of values that match a particular title? It could be than compared with normalized periods, capitalization and whitespaces, i.e.

- user-entered `Dr`, `dr.` and `Dr.` would be normalized and matched against `Dr.`
- user-entered `doctor` and `Doctor` would be normalized and matched
- user-entered `doc`, `Doc.` and `doc` would be normalized and matched etc.

This sounds like a mind-numbing task though going through variations of misters etc. *Really* consider making it into a normalized dropdown in the first place; the only thing that would be harder to process than this would be a non-normalized address field :)

Comment: Very much agreed. Sadly, I have no control over the original input (the user-generated title is collected elsewhere, saved into a database, and then I try to automatically select stuff for the user to lighten the workload of filling out a lengthy form)

Comment: Well that's a shame, but definitely thumbs up for the effort to make the form easier for end users to fill out! Also: while this could be, and likely is, overkill for only title matching, here is the link to the fuzzy search page I was talking about: http://code.google.com/p/yeti-witch/ Once the algorithm is finalized, maybe would help with the code :)

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with overkill codes for tiny details. 80% of the code makes for 20% of the functionality. :) -- Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!